# How to arrange elements inside a Row, where one element has infinite width?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to translate the following layout to Compose:

[image]

As you can see, the text on the left can be long, but it's allowed to wrap - the important thing is that it leaves enough space for the text on the right to be rendered. Here's what it looks like in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout"
    >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/stock_name"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/holding_quantity"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:text="Vanguard Total Stock Market Index Fund ETF Shares"
      />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/holding_quantity"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
      android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:text="10"
      />
</merge>
```

I'm struggling to find the right `Row` configuration that would work:

```
@Composable fun HoldingView() {
  Row {
    val typography = MaterialTheme.typography
    Text("Vanguard Total Stock Market Index Fund ETF Shares", style = typography.body1)
    Spacer(Modifier.preferredWidth(16.dp))
    Text("10", style = typography.h4, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
  }
}
```

Without any extra modifiers, this simply pushes the text on the right out of bounds:

[image]

Things I've tried without any luck:

- Playing with various [`Arrangement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement) options, such as [`SpaceBetween`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/Arrangement#SpaceBetween:androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.HorizontalOrVertical)
- Assigning a `Modifier.weight(1f)` to the second `Text`

Neither of these had any effect on how the views are laid out. Is there a configuration that would work for this use case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use `Modifier.weight(1f)` (which is available on the `RowScope` within the `Row{ ... }`) on the `Text` that you want to fill available space after all the other elements are laid out (that is, in your case, the *first* one).

So your example would look like:

```kotlin
Row {
    val typography = MaterialTheme.typography
    Text(
        "Vanguard Total Stock Market Index Fund ETF Shares",
        style = typography.body1,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    Spacer(Modifier.preferredWidth(16.dp))
    Text("10", style = typography.h4, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
}
```

which renders as (poor cropping on my screenshot messing with the margins on the edges notwithstanding)
[image: screenshot of "Vanguard Total Stock Market Index Fund ETF Shares" and "10" both visible in a row]